# How do you pass MVC's trusted credentials to a sub project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using a trusted connection and Entity Framework, my MVC project links to a SQL on another server without a problem.

That project, however, calls another sub project which uses Linq to access the same server, but it doesn't use the trusted connection. Instead it attempts to connect via the servername$. I believe I need to pass the trusted credentials to the sub project, but I don't know how.

Comment: show some code in terms of how it does it currently.

Comment: What do you mean "subproject"? If your web app references other class projects, they will run under the same account - the application pool's. Is the account used by the application pool a local account or a domain account? If it's a local (app pool account, network service etc), connecting to any remote server will  use the *server's* account (ie `servername$`). Most likely the first SQL Server has a login for `servername$`. You need to use a domain account for the application account to avoid such issues

Comment: @Ahmedilyas this is a permissions issue, it isn't code related.

Comment: understood but it is a code issue - you haven't shown how the code works. without not knowing, how can we provide a solution?